# face detection through webcam using java in ubuntu linux

Tags: java

I am working on a project which requires face detection through webcam.Suggest me any libraries that I can use to do this.i found one named openCV but it is for windows only.plz suggest some other methods also.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV is almost a standard in computer vision. It works on both unix like and windows platforms - http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/. Follow the installation manual and the basic tutorials to get started.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [processing library](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/) that calls OpenCV functions. That way you could use the OpenCV functionality without going down to c++ yourself. You can use the processing library with java without using the whole processing stuff.